# In memory file as an argument to process in Java on Linux

Tags: java, linux, process, arguments

I am trying to pass a Java object to a process that accepts a file as an argument. The OS is Linux. Namely, there is an open-source antivirus called ClamAV. It provides a command line tool called "clamscan". We can tell clamscan to scan a file as following:

clamscan -d [RuleFilePath] [FileToScanPath]

I will call this process through ProcessBuilder. The thing is, I don't want to create real files and save them to disk to call this process. Is there any way to run it with Java objects in memory? Thank you

Comment: What about a memory disk device?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is possible with [named pipes](http://carminedimascio.com/2014/01/named-pipes-with-java/), but quite difficult to get right.

I would suggest using [tmpfs as a RAM disk file system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66329/creating-a-ram-disk-on-linux) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create temp file form java before process and after end of process delete file.